# smart way to design crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to create a crystal report that will match a pdf file. The info in the pdf file is a combination of form fields and instructions layed out in a table format. The crystal report should exactly match the pdf file because I will export the report to pdf later.

is there a smart way of quickly designing the rpt file? like converting the pdf file to an rpt file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better off just building the rpt file from the ground up -- there are no utilities I'm aware of that can covert the PDF to a RPT file.

Comment: Thanks litte... and heather... i did the same.

Comment: I've had to do exactly this in the past.  Luckily, it's pretty easy in the CR Designer to export a report to PDF so you can quickly compare your results to the target document.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with LittleBobbyTables in that I don't know of a pdf to Crystal Reports converter so you'll have to build the report on your own from scratch, but you may look into other options instead of Crystal Reports if possible.

Of course it's hard for me to give a good solution since I don't know the drivers behind the decision to use Crystal Reports, but if you are looking to display the data in a web page, Adobe has a pdf to HTML converter [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/access_onlinetools.html) that you may be able to start off with. You put the url to the pdf form and it converts it to HTML or Text. I tried it and thought it did work, it wasn't really close in the look and feel of the original pdf form so you can use it to get you part of the way and then you can wire up the data portion to display your data. Just throwing out another option instead of wedding yourself to Crystal Reports. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Dusty, I created the report from ground up.